# Как пофиксить консоль в vs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

В visual studio 2019 когда запускаю программу - не выводится информация в консоли, [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Хотя час назад консоль работала, все ок было, как пофиксить?

Comment: А если скролл к началу промотать?

Comment: @Qwertiy речь, видимо, про горизонтальный скрол, который как-то сразу и не заметно, имхо.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну я как-то сразу заметил на скриншоте.

Comment: Да не в scroll дело, у меня данные в консоли не отображались, там программа файловый менеджер была, уже пофиксил сам, спасибо, что откликнулись).